# How to set Body format to HTML in C# Email

Tags: c#, html, email, smtp

I have the following code to create and send an email:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("email@address.com", "Summary");
var toAddress = new MailAddress(dReader["Email"].ToString(), dReader["FirstName"].ToString());
const string fromPassword = "####";
const string subject = "Summary";
string body = bodyText;

//Sets the smpt server of the hosting account to send
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smpt@smpt.com",
    Port = 587,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)                        
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{                       
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

How can I set the message body to HTML?

Comment: You should also put `var smtp = new SmtpClient` in a `using` as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml` (from MSDN):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the mail message body is in
>   Html.

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{                       
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true // this property
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the MailMessage.BodyFormat property to MailFormat.Html, and then dump the contents of your html file to the MailMessage.Body property:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(htmlFilePath)) // Path to your 
{                                                         // HTML file
    MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
    myMail.From = "from@microsoft.com";
    myMail.To = "to@microsoft.com";
    myMail.Subject = "HTML Message";
    myMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

    myMail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();  // Load the content from your file...
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `mailMessage.IsBodyHtml` to true. Then your mail message will get rendered in HTML format.

Comment: Why would you come in nearly a year later to post a duplicate [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15749389/621962)?