# How to format text in email when using smtp

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm using the following method to send an email. I want to be able to format the email with bold text.

Ex.

**From:**  name

**Email:**  email address

**Message:**  message

How would I do this?

```
    protected void SendMail()
    {
        var fromAddress = "myemail@gmail.com";
        var toAddress = "myotheremail@gmail.com";
        const string fromPassword = "mypassword";

        string subject = "New Email from Website";
        string body = "From: " + name.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + email.Text + "\n";
        body += "Message: \n" + message.Text + "\n";

        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Body format to HTML in C# Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749368/how-to-set-body-format-to-html-in-c-sharp-email)

Comment: Create a MailMessage and set the IsBodyHtml property = true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set isBodyHtml to true, the following code describes it,
To send a bold text you can use "`<b> My bold text </b>` ".
To send an italicized text you can use "`<i> Italic text </i>` ".
To send an underlined text you can use "`<u> underlined text </u>`".

You can copy and use the following method. By using this method, it will be very easy to send emails.

```
public static bool SendEmail(string To, string ToName, string From, string FromName, string Subject, string Body, bool IsBodyHTML)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress FromAddr = new MailAddress(From, FromName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        MailAddress ToAddr = new MailAddress(To, ToName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your email address", "your password")
        };

        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(FromAddr, ToAddr)
        {
            Subject = Subject,
            Body = Body,
            IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHTML,
            BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,

        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When you call this method call it like this

```
 SendEmail("Here address to" , "Here to name" , "Here from", "here from name", "here subject" , here Body, " Here whether HTML or Plain" )
```

Answer (score 4):

You need only few minor changes.

1. say `IsBodyHtml` is `true`
2. replace all `\n` with `<br/>`

and here's the final the code

```
protected void SendMail()
{
    var fromAddress = "myemail@gmail.com";
    var toAddress = "myotheremail@gmail.com";
    const string fromPassword = "mypassword";

    string subject = "New Email from Website";
    string body = "From: " + name.Text + "<br/>";
    body += "Email: " + email.Text + "<br/>";
    body += "Message: <br/>" + message.Text + "<br/>";

    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body,IsBodyHtml:true);
}
```

Hope that helps.